# Is there a relation between time dilation and (relativistic) mass increase?

Tags: special-relativity, mass, mass-energy, time-dilation

I noticed that what once called *relativistic mass increase* and now is called energy increase is ruled by the same formula [the Lorenz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Overview_of_formulae)  of time dilation?

The formula is too particular to suggest a mere coincidence, can you explain what is the relation between the two phenomena and, in case, which determines which?

Comment: read this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/tdil.html

Comment: @annav, does that article explain the relation? How does time influence mass and viceversa?

Comment: I don't think it is any more serious than these two parameters increasing as you approach the speed of light. Apparently they increase at the same rate, hence the same formula.

Comment: @GRrocks, are you saying it is just a coincidence? that would be amazing

Comment: I wouldn't put it as a 'coincidence'....they both increase as your speed increases, and there are perfectly valid physical arguments to explain why. However, the only common thing in this context is the speed; everything else, I believe, is quite independently explainable.

Comment: It's not a coincidence because time dilation and length contraction are described by components of one 4-vector and relativistic energy and momentum are the components of another 4-vector and both 4-vectors transform the same under Lorentz transformations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-vector.

Comment: @CuriousOne, surely *length* and time are connected and interdependent,  but the question is asking the relation between *mass* and time. Why should time dilation influence the mass of a particle? What is the evidence or even the theoretical assumption?

Comment: as Curious said. It is the Lorenz transformations applied to each system under observation. in the link "it follows from the Lorentz transformation when collisions are described from a fixed and moving reference frame, where it arises as a result of conservation of momentum. "

Comment: @annav, I read that and it is not clear to me, I'd appreciate if you could explain it in an answer.

Comment: Mass doesn't change at all. Take a look at the modern way these quantities are being written and then you can see why this isn't "just a coincidence". The ratios can't be any other way.

Comment: look at the lorenz transformation of the two four vectors  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/vec4.html